# Photographer creating PhotoShop action help needed

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5, photoshop-action

I need to create an action that will do the following:

1. Start with a folder of NEF files.
2. Open one at a time and apply adjustments, ie. Crop, exposure, levels, saturation and sharpening as needed.
3. Save for Print at 300 dpi
4. Save for the Web by reducing to 72 dpi and resizing to 723 X 480 pixels and renaming with WEB as a prefix in the name.
5. Load the next file and repeat steps 2 thru 4.

How can this action be created so I can make the changes when the action pauses between the appropriate steps?
Or can you suggest a site that can answer this question?

Comment: You'd get a better response asking photography questions on [http://photo.stackexchange.com/](http://photo.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @John Please don't suggest other sites without telling the OP that the question can be migrated there. Otherwise this will lead to double-posting, which is not allowed. Thanks

Comment: True. I kind of expected someone to migrate this already (I'd do it myself if I had the rights). Loren Sr - please don't re-post the same question on the other forum.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to interact mid way through, this would need to be several actions.

I'd suggest creating a droplet `File > Automate > Create Droplet`. It is basically a shortcut icon you can place on your desktop that runs a PS action. If you create an action droplet for each stage of your process, you can just drag and drop your images onto the droplets without having to manually open them up in Photoshop.

Also, if you upgrade to Creative Cloud, the camera raw filter has a MAJOR upgrade in that you can apply it non destructively as a filter, instead of actually editing your raw file. It also works on non-raw formats, so you have all the camera raw features (exposure, vignetting, saturation etc... ) working on a JPEG for example.